# How to make text centered vertically in Android compose?

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose, vertical-alignment

I am working on my first app fully designed by Compose.

I need to centralize vertically text with the `Text()` compose component. In traditional Android dev practice I did this over alignment property. `Text()` compose also has alignment property, but at this moment it has limited capacity (`Alignment.Horizontal()` is only allowed), despite on I noticed different alignment values within `Text()` when made a research in web. Similar case for `Column()` - it also has alignment property `.wrapContentSize()` and also has limitation on values that could be used here, despite on quick research in web shows it may receive `CenterVertically` too.

What is your way to achieve this visual effect? The full code piece is below

```
@ExperimentalUnitApi
@Composable
fun TripBookingContent(state: PassengerTripUiState.TripBookUiState) {
    Log.d(App.TAG, "[screen] TripBookingContent")
    val baselineGrid = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.baseline_grid)
    val mainPadding = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.main_margin_compact)
    var componentSpace = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.component_space)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(
                paddingValues = PaddingValues(
                    horizontal = mainPadding,
                    vertical = baselineGrid
                )
            )
    ) {
        TripViewItem(
            data = state.trip,
            {},
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = baselineGrid)
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.booking_screen_driver),
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
            style = TextStyle(textIndent = TextIndent(firstLine = TextUnit(16F, TextUnitType.Sp))),
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(componentSpace)
                .padding(start = baselineGrid)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.design_default_color_secondary_variant))
        )
        Log.d(App.TAG, "[state] state.driver - ${state}")
        Log.d(App.TAG, "[state] state.driver.toDriver() - ${state.driver}")
        DriverCardContent(data = state.driver)

        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.booking_screen_msg),
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
            style = TextStyle(textIndent = TextIndent(firstLine = TextUnit(16F, TextUnitType.Sp))),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
//                .height(componentSpace)
                .height(32.dp)
                .padding(start = baselineGrid)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
        )
        /**
         * Disable book button at current (alfa version), for more details
         * */
        Button(
            onClick = { /* no op */ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .alpha(0F)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(baselineGrid)
                .height(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.button_height)),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                contentColor = Color.White
            ),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.booking_screen_confirm_button),
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE
My final solution become this one below. I have to move padding and background to the Box() layer to achieve text in center both vertically and horizontally.

```
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(32.dp)
                .padding(start = baselineGrid)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.booking_screen_msg),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
                style = TextStyle(textIndent = TextIndent(firstLine = TextUnit(16F, TextUnitType.Sp))),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
/*                modifier = Modifier
//                .height(componentSpace)
                    .height(32.dp)
                    .padding(start = baselineGrid)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorPrimaryDark))*/
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be done in several ways. As mentioned in other answer you can use `Modifier.wrapContentSize()`, `Modifier.layout` which is very similar to how wrapContentSize modifier implemented , it's how size Modifers are implemented, they basically change, update or limit Constraints and measure and layout their contents.

`Modifier.wrapContentSize` changes
minimum width and height to 0, and because of that you would be able measure content in that range instead of size Modifier or Constraints that return fixed min,max width range. such as min=200.dp, max=200.dp. If you change min range to 0 your content gets measured with it's actual content dimensions and it gets placed in any aligment.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    Text(
        text = "Hello world",
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
            .size(200.dp)
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable =
                    measurable.measure(
                        // This is how wrapContent works
                        constraints.copy(minWidth = 0, minHeight = 0)
                    )
                layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
                 // This is how wrapContent alignment works
                    val x = (constraints.maxWidth - placeable.width) / 2
                    val y = (constraints.maxHeight - placeable.height) / 2
                    placeable.placeRelative(x, y)
                }
            },
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

or use `Box()` with `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center`. There are also CenterStart and CenterEnd options for alignment either.

```
   Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Text",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Is the Box the only option for this? Text(), Column() are misfit for this task, but what about Card() or some other component?

Comment: If you click `Card`with cmd/crtl + click you will see that Card source is a `Surface` and Surface itself is also a Box with `contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopStart`. So it's possible with Box or you can create your own composable with `Layout`and use place according to your needs. I have tutorial about layouts and many other things if you are interested.

Comment: With custom `Layout` and `Modifier` you can have your own alignment scheme like in this [image](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/screenshots/tutorial3_3_1.png)

Answer (score 58):

It is possible to center text vertically IF your Text widget has a height modifier for example - `Text(text="example", modifier=Modifier.height(100.dp)` You can use the **`wrapContentHeight`** modifier to align text vertically for example

```
Text(
    text = "Example",
    modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp)
        .height(100.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Cyan)
        .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically),
    color = Color.Black,
    fontSize = 42.sp,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Right
)
```

Comment: my text doesn't have a fixed height value but has minLines and it doesn't help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738733/text-is-not-centered-vertically-with-textalign-textalign-center-only-horizont

Comment: empty `wrapContentSize` works like a charm

Answer (score 9):

Alignment modifiers depend on the parent, which is how it supposed to be, in a vertical list (column) vertical alignment is handled by the parent (which is great that compose can enforce this)

Soo in your case you probably need a different hierarchy. For ex: `Box` instead of `Column`. Alternatively you can play around with the size of the `Text`, make it `200dp` in height for example and use `textAlign`, to center it's text.

For reference:

- `Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)` -> Specifies alignment of children
- `Text(text = "example", modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize().align())` -> Specifies alignment of `Text` composable under parent
- `Text(text = "example", textAlign = TextAlign.Center)` -> specifies alignment of text, inside composable, using this with `wrapContentSize()` won't have any effect, since the Composable has the same size as it's content text

Answer (score 0):

For centering the text in a Text you can also use TextStyle, example:

```
val body = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 22.sp,
        lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
            alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Proportional,
            trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
        )
    )
```

LineHeightStyle you can set its alignment and trim.

TextAlign doesnt work with aligning Vertically, however in here you can.