# Text is not centered vertically with textAlign = TextAlign.Center when using minLines, only horizontally

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Black),
    minLines = 3,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    text = "Not centered vertically"
)
```

[image]

How can I center text by vertically and horizontally of its container when current lines count is less then minimum lines?

Answer (score 1):

The `textAlign` attributes defines only how to align text horizontally.

You can use the `TextMeasurer` to measure a text and check if the width > width of the `text`. In this case the `text` will occupy more than 1 line in the `Text` composable

In this example I am using the screen width (since you are using `fillMaxWidth()`).

```
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult =
        textMeasurer.measure(
            text = AnnotatedString(text),
            style = LocalTextStyle.current
        )
    val widthText = textLayoutResult.size.width

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidth = density.run { configuration.screenWidthDp.dp.toPx()}

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Black),
        minLines = 3,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        text = if (widthText < screenWidth)  "\n" + text else text,
        color = White,
    )
```

[image]

Comment: How do we get minLines in Text, was not getting btw

Comment: @J.K It was introduced in M3 with 1.1.0-alpha02 and M2 with 1.4.0-alpha02.

Answer (score 1):

`textAlign` is only responsible for horizontal alignment, usually to control vertical alignment you can use a container.

I like to use a technique where you add an invisible view that gives the layout some size guides, and then place the actual view using the parent alignment.

In this case, the blank text with `minLines` will take the necessary height, and the actual text will be centered in the box.

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Black)
) {
    Text("", minLines = 3)
    Text(
        "Centered vertically",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        color = Color.White,
    )
}
```

[image]